# Wordpress duplicator moving from subdomain to root/domain

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, subdomain

I created Wordpress website on localhost. I moved wordpress with duplicator plugin to subdomain for testing (dev.example.com). I created new mysql database and user for subdomain. Everything works fine.

Now, I would to move my wordpress from subdomain to main domain/root. On existing root there is still old website. I am going to delete everything in public_html.

Can i create new mysql database and user for root/domain; and move wordpress with duplicator plugin... just like i did moving from localhost to subdomain (I created new database for subdomain).

Is the process the same? Or is there better way moving from subdomain to root.

Best,

Klemen

Answer (score 0):

Essentially yes you can do this, just make sure you backup the live site before overwriting it.

I use Duplicator all the time for migrating local dev sites to live domains.

Good luck!